# Mean Stack - can using a "Globals" module cause issues when werving a web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a variable (a constructed filename) that I need to get from within an API in one file to be stored as a variable in another file.

The way my code is set up, there's not really a way (that I can think of) to get this variable from one file to another without using globals. I've been looking around at a few different methods and decided to create a globals module (globals.js):

```
var globals = {
    'new_img': ''
}

module.exports = globals;
```

I've written:

```
var globals        = require('./public/js/globals');
```

In my server.js and in my routes.js so that all of my API's and controllers have access to this module.

When I serve this web application and multiple people have their own instances of the webpage, will they all be using the same globals module? This is *not* my desired effect. What would be better ways of going about this?

Comment: So `new_img` would be variable based on the user?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: you need to push everyone's variables based on their id `global[id] = globals_id` and then retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes they will be using the **same** instance.

That pattern is a singleton, you're exporting and making global a variable, the same spot in memory will be visibile by the whole app.

With the help of the debugger you can analyze the `require` code in depth and see that Nodejs will cache the result of that call and return the same instance everytime.

**NodeJS source code**:

[image]
[image]

if your desired result is to have different instances you can shallow clone the object.

```
var globals  = _.extend({}, require('./public/js/globals')); //ecma5 + underscore.js

var globals = Object.assign({}, require('./public/js/globals')); //ecma6
```